# I create the SSR for the react app using the expree but got error when run

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, server-side-rendering

I created the ssr for react app. For that i am using express.
Created the folder server in root. In that for 2 file index.js, server.js.
Below are the code,

[image]

**server.js file**

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import App from "../src/App";

const app = express();

app.use("^/$", (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve("./build/index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send("Some error happened");
        }

        const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
                <App />
            </StaticRouter>
        );

        return res.send(
            data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`)
        );
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")));

app.listen(3005, () => {
    console.log("App is launched");
});
```

**Index.js**

```
require("@babel/register")({
    ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
});

require("./server");
```

To run the ssr I run the command node server/index